# Webgl using coordinates from a texture

Tags: javascript, colors, webgl, shader

In webgl I created a scene where I have 4 objects, and I added different textures on each of them. Each texture is passed on to the shader via uniform variables. I am trying to make half of one of my objects red. But every time I try to change half of one of the objects to red, i somehow get the half of every texture red. The following is what I have in my fragment shader at the moment.

```
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
uniform sampler2D Texture2;
vec4 a = texture2D(Texture2, vTextureCoord);
if(a.t>0.5)
{
gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)
}
else
{
gl_FragColor = vec4(t.x,0.0,0.0,1.0)
}
```

So to sum up my question, how can I get half of only one of my textures to red?

Thank you

Comment: @gman oh sorry I had uniform sampler2D but i guess when i was typing the question i got confused with varying vec2. but i fixed the question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `t.x`? You're looking up a color from a texture, then based on the green value of the texel you looked up from texture `a.t`, if that texel's green value is `> 0.5` you're deciding to return either red or `vec4(t.x, 0, 0, 1)` which is another shade of red.

I'm guessing from your description you want to choose red based on the texture coordinates, not the texture's texel colors. In that case you want

```
if (vTextureCoord.t > 0.5)  // If the texture coordinate's t is > 0.5
```

Instead of

```
if (a.t)   // If the texel's green value is > 0.5
```

And if you want to choose the texture color or red then you'd do this

```
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
uniform sampler2D Texture2;

void main() {
  vec4 a = texture2D(Texture2, vTextureCoord);
  if (vTextureCoord.t > 0.5)
  {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
  }
  else
  {
    gl_FragColor = a;
  }
}
```

You could also do this

```
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
uniform sampler2D Texture2;

void main() {
  vec4 a = texture2D(Texture2, vTextureCoord);
  gl_FragColor = (vTextureCoord.t > 0.5) ? vec4(1,0,0,1) : a;
}
```

or this

```
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
uniform sampler2D Texture2;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = (vTextureCoord.t > 0.5) ? vec4(1,0,0,1) : texture2D(Texture2, vTextureCoord);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the great answer. It was very very useful. only problem i have now is that, half of my objects in my scene turn in to red, but I only want to change the color of one of the objects

Comment: use another shader or, add a uniform bool, or add in some kind of multiplier you can set to 0 or 1, etc..